# I'm a designer that is having some problems with SMARTGWT

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

This is kind of a trick question. I started working in a company that uses this framework, the thing is that they can't do simple things I design. The UI seems outdated and simply awful. I wanted to know what do you think about this framework? Am I being dumb to ask to start using new front-end frameworks?

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to say that i know smartgwt that much, but from the showcase looks like something designed to enterprise application with really complex UI, smartgwt is based on GWT, and there is many alternatives some are old and some are old, [sencha GXT](https://www.sencha.com/products/gxt/#overview) is one, other newer and more modern alternative are [GWT material design](https://gwtmaterialdesign.github.io/gwt-material-demo/#about) and the future proofed which is already working with j2cl and the next version of GWT  -GWT3.0- is [domino-ui](https://dominokit.github.io/domino-ui-demo/index.html?theme=indigo#home).

and no you are not dumb for asking to start using new frontend frameworks, but you also needs to count for the cost of the switch, is it worth the switch? what is the size of the application? how many developers working on that application? how much logic is shared with the server? can you really recruit enough people for the new framework? what is the switch plan and how you make sure it will work out? .. so simply there is more to it than just what framework you want to use.

And really i dont think this is a good place to ask the question, but maybe you need to discuss with people who may know the framework better, maybe you need to give the [gwt gitter channel](https://gitter.im/gwtproject/gwt) a try